# Vmware Vsphere snapshot restore Win2008 R2 BOOTMGR is missing

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware, snapshot, bios

I took a snapshot using Vsphere 5.1 yesterday for my Windows 2008 R2 VM. Today when I restored my VM using this snapshot, the VM failed to start up and it is telling me with the following message:
"BOOTMGR is missing, Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart"

A little search online seems to fetch the conclusion that this happens from time to time with Windows 2008 or windows 7 VMs, in that when the VM software compressed the system to make a snapshot, it compressed the boot section too, and on restore the guest OS did not like this, and can not find the boot bios.

Is there anyway I can restore this? Perhaps from the Vsphere command line to rebuild the bootmgr?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by booting from Windows 2008 CD, going to recovery and then command prompt and doing these commands:

Type Bootrec /RebuildBcd, and then press ENTER. 
Reboot, go back into recovery mode and command prompt again, this time selecting the windows 2008 installation that was rebuilt.
Go to X:\Sources\Recovery and run startrep.exe